# Probability of different outcome after a re-election

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Here is the problem:

> (a) During an election involving 50,000,000 votes, the final tally between two candidates differed by 500 votes. Assuming the votes cast are a subset of an infinitely large population, if the election is held again (drawing 50,000,0000 new votes from the infinitely large population) what is the probability that the outcome is different (i.e. the winner is different?) ?
>
> (b) Now, assume that, for an election of $N=5\times 10^7$ votes, the theoretical mean
> difference between the votes of the two candidates is 500. Assuming an infinitely large population, how many votes $N2$ would need to be cast, so that a repeat draw of $N2$ votes would have a 99% probability of the result being the same? (You may solve this numerically, but describe how you do so analytically).

As a warning, this is a statistic problem from an undergraduate astrophysics class so don't assume that I know too much from statistics .

For (a), I calculated the number of people that voted for each candidate ($C_1= 25 000 250$ and $C_2=24 999 750$). After this, I thought that I could use, for example $C_1$, to generate a normal distribution with mean $C_1$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{C_1}$ and compute $P(0<x<25000000)$ (meaning that $C_1$ lost the election). But, then, I realized there was two problems with what I did. First, when I did the same thing with $C_2$ instead of $C_1$ and then compute $P(25000000<x<50000000)$ I got a different result which I think is not normal and I think this comes from my second problem. This second problem is that $x$ takes values from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ meaning that when integrating as I did above, I left out the tail part on both sides which resulted in a different probability. So I looked on the Internet a way to restrict the PDF to only an interval but then I saw a complicated function (evolving the error function) and I really think this is not the way my teacher wants us to solve this.

For (b), I feel like it's the opposite problem meaning that we know the probability and we look for the number of voters. So finding the answer in part (a) will probably help me a lot. But I'm still a bit confused since the probability for the result to be the same is $P(x=x_1)$ (if $x=x_1$ is the first result of the election) and this is always zero.

EDIT: I tried with a Poisson distribution too since I realised those were discrete but I get a sum that I can't evaluate: $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{25000000} \frac{25000250^n}{n!}\,e^{-25000250}$

Comment: Use binomials and Bernoulli distributions. There is no need for normal distributions here.

Comment: @Digitallis I tried this but again, I end up with a sum that can't be computed easily: $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{25000000} \binom{50000000}{k}\left(\frac{25000250}{50000000}\right)^k \left(\frac{24999750}{50000000}\right)^{50000000-k}$

Comment: Maybe you can use the central limit theorem to approximate the binomial by a normal distribution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Central_limit_theorem